# Vagrant docker provider slow build

Tags: docker, vagrant, vagrantfile, dockerfile, vagrant-windows

I am trying to use Vagrant with docker provider on windows machine.
I have Vagrantfile like this:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.define "app" do |app|
        app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.name = "app"
            d.build_dir = "."
            d.vagrant_machine = "dockerhost"
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "./DockerhostVagrantfile"
        end
    end
end
```

Docker host definition like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "smb"
    config.vm.provision "docker"
    config.vm.define "dockerhost"
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port",
    guest: 8080, host: 8080
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.name = "dockerhost"
    end
end
```

And Docker container like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

WORKDIR /vagrant/application
# .... install stuff
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

The problem is whenever I do `vagrant docker-run app -- bash` and dockerimage has to be rebuild the process takes soo long.

```
// ....
app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 180.5 MB
app: Sending build context to Docker daemon   181 MB
app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 181.6 MB
// ....
```

I think this is because folder inside `dockerhost` is mount with `vboxfs` (which I found terribly slow).

Is there any way I can enforce Vagrant to use `smb`?

Is problem with performance caused by anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly I found a solution how to use `smb` instead of `vboxfs` to mount `docker build directory`.

As it states here https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/745bdf676675e7b1f25fd7df5a4ed48b582b6dc7

It is possible to define `host_vm_build_dir_options` property. So I modified my `Vagrantfile` like this:

```
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'
Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.define "app" do |app|
        app.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.name = "app"
            d.build_dir = "."
            d.vagrant_machine = "dockerhost"
            d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "./DockerhostVagrantfile"
            d.host_vm_build_dir_options = {
                type: "smb"
            }
        end
    end
end
```

Anyway the **real problem** with speed was caused by having `Dockerfile` inside my root of project so all files were sent to the host. I solved that by moving it to Docker folder where is only the Dockerfile.